# Calculate new position for line with moving edges

Tags: math, language-agnostic, drawing

When a line is moving with a known forward speed at both edges, how do I calculate the new position of the line (after N m/s)? The speeds at both edges can either be positive or negative.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The line is given by its two endpoints, P and Q, which change their positions over time.
At time 0, P is at P_0 (which has coordinates: (P_0_x,  P_0_y)), and Q is at Q_0 = (Q_0_x, Q_0_y).

P is moving with some v_P = (v_P_x, v_P_y) velocity at every second. Q's velocity is denoted by v_Q = (v_Q_x, v_Q_y).

So P at time t is at P_t = P_0 + t * v_P = (P_0_x + t * v_P_x, P_0_y + t * v_P_y).

In a similar way: Q_t = (Q_0_x + t * v_Q_x, Q_0_y + t * v_Q_y).

These become the endpoints of the line at time t, which identify the line itself.